# _NSZeroData _fastCharacterContents error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing native iOS application. my app crashes with error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSZeroData _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14dcba60'
```

what this means? Somebody please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It means you called a method on a class that does not exist.  I cannot provide more information without a stacktrace and the relevant code.

Comment: You or someone else is sending a message named fastCharacterContents to an object of class NSZeroData, and that class doesn't understand the message. It is most likely casused by a bug in your code. You'll need to learn basic debugging using Xcode.